# Multi-touch support for RVIZ visualizer

Tags: ros, rviz, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I am trying to visualize maps on RVIZ on a touch screen display with multi-touch support. Rviz visualization window doesn't seem to support touch. The only thing i can do it rotate, pinch zoom or pan doesn't work, even though the gesture recognition is turned on in the OS.

I was looking into the tutorials, for rviz, and the `rviz::VisualizationManager` allows only mouse events and not touch events. Is my understanding right, is there any way around it??

Any ideas for panning and zooming the maps are appreciated.

I am using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276498/multi-touch-support-for-rviz-visualizer/) by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2017-11-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no built-in touch support in RViz right now, but it is an Ogre application, so I would suggest looking for information on (multi-)touch support there.

> Any ideas for panning and zooming the maps are appreciated.

RViz is a mouse-driven application, so if you can somehow convert touch events into mouse events (clicks, drags, wheel, etc), that should allow you to work around the current limitations.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julien Audet](https://answers.ros.org/users/40390/julien-audet/) on 2019-03-29**:
I haven't tried it yet, but I think Touchégg [1] would work for converting touch events into mouse events in RViz. You can choose which mouse events are triggered by the touch events. I'll try in a month when I will have my touchscreen shipped.

[1] https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg

**Comment by [Julien Audet](https://answers.ros.org/users/40390/julien-audet/) on 2019-07-10**:
I finally tried it, and it works pretty well with touchegg!

**Comment by [rbukovec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63709/rbukovec/) on 2020-11-19**:
Hey Julien, I am trying to get this to work now on RVIZ. I have downloaded touchegg, but I keep getting an error message when trying to use multi-touch for rviz.

Gesture begin detected
Gesture information:
Fingers: 2
Type: PINCH
Direction: OUT
Gesture performed on app: rviz
No action configured for this gesture
Ignoring this gesture. This could mean no action is configured, the configured action is not supported or that it was performed in a system window (panel, dock, desktop, etc)

I have even went into the touchegg.config file and added this code, but still this will not work in Rviz. Adding code in next comment because it was too long

**Comment by [rbukovec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63709/rbukovec/) on 2020-11-19**:
enter code here

```
  <application name="rviz">
    <gesture type="PINCH" fingers="2" direction="IN">
      <action type="SEND_KEYS">
        <repeat>true</repeat>
        <modifiers>Control_L</modifiers>
        <keys>KP_Subtract</keys>
        <decreaseKeys>KP_Add</decreaseKeys>
      </action>
    </gesture>

    <gesture type="PINCH" fingers="2" direction="OUT">
      <action type="SEND_KEYS">
        <repeat>true</repeat>
        <modifiers>Control_L</modifiers>
        <keys>KP_Add</keys>
        <decreaseKeys>KP_Subtract</decreaseKeys>
      </action>
    </gesture>
  </application>
```

**Comment by [rbukovec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63709/rbukovec/) on 2020-11-19**:
Actually, I now have it working using the code above. Touchegg says that two finger pinch is working when I try to zoom in and out on rviz, but it does not actually zoom in and out on rviz? Any Ideas?

**Comment by [Julien Audet](https://answers.ros.org/users/40390/julien-audet/) on 2020-11-21**:
If I remember right, I couldn't make the two finger pinch work for zoom in or zoom out, but it did work with two finger swipe up/down for zoom in/out, this was my touchegg configuration :

```
<gesture type="DRAG" fingers="2" direction="UP">
      <action type="SCROLL">SPEED=7:INVERTED=true</action>
</gesture>

<gesture type="DRAG" fingers="2" direction="DOWN">
      <action type="SCROLL">SPEED=1:INVERTED=true</action>
</gesture>
```

**Comment by [lancezzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/62922/lancezzz/) on 2020-11-22**:
I am trying to use rviz with touchegg as well. I noticed the same as rbukovec, zoom in and zoom out works when I use two fingers swipe up/down. In addition, I noticed that whenever I touch the screen with one finger, the rviz with change to another viewpoint, a totally undesired behavior. I have no idea what causes this. Lastly, I am wondering if it is possible to use 2D Navi Goal tool in rviz?